# Quicksort Algorithm won't complete in worst case

Tags: java, sorting, quicksort

For a coursework assignment I have been tasked with implementing a basic Quicksort Algorithm. I have implemented what I thought to be a working Quicksort, however it doesn't work for one particular array that we have to test. This array is supposed to be a worst case and should understandably take more comparisons, but I simply cannot get it to produce a sorted array in this case.

**Pseudo Code:**

Begin quickSort

if (R > L) then

p := partition(A,L,R);

quickSort(A,L,p-1);

quickSort(A,p+1,R);

fi

End

Begin partition

v := A[right]

pL := left; pR := right-1;

while (pL < pR) do

while (A[pL] < v) do 
pL:=pL+1
od
while (A[pR]>=v and pR>left) do

pR:=pR-1

od

if (pL < pR) then

swap(A,pL,pR)

fi

od

swap(A,pL,right);

return pL;

**The code in question:**

```
public void quickSort(int[] A, int L, int R) {
    if (L < R) {
        int p = partition(A, L, R);
        quickSort(A, L, p - 1);
        quickSort(A, p + 1, R);
    }
}
private int partition(int[] A, int left, int right) {
    int pivot = A[right];
    int pointerLeft = left;
    int pointerRight = right - 1;
    while (pointerLeft < pointerRight) {
        while (A[pointerLeft] < pivot) {
            pointerLeft = pointerLeft + 1;
            compQS++;
        }
        while (A[pointerRight] > pivot && pointerRight > left) {
            pointerRight = pointerRight - 1;
            compQS++;
        }
        if (pointerLeft < pointerRight) {
            swap(A, pointerLeft, pointerRight);
        }
    }
    swap(A, pointerLeft, right);
    return pointerLeft;

}

private void swap(int[] A, int i, int j) {
    int temp = A[i];
    A[i] = A[j];
    A[j] = temp;
}
```

**The array in question:**

1
3
41
5
6
9
11
20
21
22
23
24
26
28
29
30
33
39
41
41
43
45
46
2
54
55
55
56
57
60
61
63
65
66
67
69
69
70
71
180
73
74
76
77
79
138
81
83
85
88
91
92
92
94
94
95
99
101
101
103
105
106
107
110
113
115
118
125
127
128
129
136
80
143
144
147
148
150
152
153
155
156
158
163
169
170
171
175
176
178
75
184
185
189
190
193
194
195
196
199

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. I can't help but think it's something to do with duplicates but can't see where my implementation is going wrong.

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code, stepping through the code line by line?

Comment: Have worked out through testing that the issue only arises when 3 duplicates are in the same array. Can anybody shed any light on where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code, two points seem fishy:

In the recursion, you write

```
   quickSort(A, L, p - 1);
   quickSort(A, p + 1, R);
```

either one should probably be p, otherwise you're missing the middle element.

The other line that seems odd is

```
swap(A, pointerLeft, right);
```

I think this will cause trouble if right (which is the pivot) is the largest value between left and right. Thinking about it, I think the problem is in your partition code when the pivot is an extreme value (smallest or largest in the set). This would coincide with the statement that the given array was a very bad case.

Comment: Hi there thanks for the quick response. I have now added the pseudo code we were to write the code from (should have done it originally). Based on this I'm told to do these things (I think). Have tried changing the above however and it causes my code to break.

Comment: The line with `while (A[pointerRight] > pivot && pointerRight > left)` doesn't exactly match the pseudo code. It says `A[pR]>=v` there.

Comment: Honestly cannot thank you enough! Code works without any problems now.

Comment: Glad to have helped. Please mark the answer then, so that others see this as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I see two possible problems in your code:

1) When you first call quickSort you are missing the mid value (you use p-1 as your right expression for the first call, and p+1 as your left expression for the second call, what happens to p?)

2) You are swapping pointerLeft with ***right***

Try this instead:

```
quicksort(A,L,p);
quicksort(A,p+1,R);
```

And

```
swap(A,pointerLeft,pointerRight);
```

Give it a try!